# How to get appId from a facebook pageTab

Tags: php, facebook

I created a page tab app in facebook, whose url is like : http://www.facebook.com/PageName/app_123456789

Is there a way to retrieve the id of the application (= 123456789) from the iframe ?

The facebook documentation mentions the "signed_request" parameter, but it does not contain this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean programatically then $facebook->appId will do the trick.
base_facebook.php has a getting function called function getAppId()

Answer (score 0):

If you created the app, shouldn't you already know the app ID? You can then put it in your code. It's not like it's going to change.

Otherwise you can use PHP or JavaScript to get the URL of the browser.
[Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url)

You might want to do it with JS
[get the parent url of iframe in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724969/get-the-parent-url-of-iframe-in-php)

Comment: I have several applications using the same code so I don't have the appId unless I use a config file (that's what I do for the moment). With PHP the only thing I can get is the URL of the iframe, and Facebook doesn't allow Javascript to access the parent URL.

Comment: I would say hard coding the appid all over the place would be bad practice. There are functions available to call this weither you know the id or not.