# Getting iframe URL location from parent document

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have document with iframe. I have no problem setting iframe's location by using this:

```
  $('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.another-domain-site.com');
```

When user navigates a few pages in that iframe, then I want to get back URL where he ends up. But when the SRC attribute of the iframe never changes from what I initially have set.

Is there a way how to get iframe's location when it changes or there is no way around same-domain policy ?

I have one more question on my mind considering question above - is there a way how browser could ask user for permission to allow this type of requests ? The same way Chrome extensions ask for extended permissions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to find a cross-domain iframe's new URL after a redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815409/is-it-possible-to-find-a-cross-domain-iframes-new-url-after-a-redirect)

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, after more searching I've found someone ask exactly same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815409/is-it-possible-to-find-a-cross-domain-iframes-new-url-after-a-redirect) and the short answer is: "Its not possible".