# iFrame Sending Parent URL

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iFrame on my website that is pointing to another domain. When the user finishes filling out a form on the site in the iFrame, the site sends my website a URL. I want to take that URL and force the parent to load that URL. I was using the following code, but it did not work.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
  if (top !== self) top.location.href = self.location.href; 
</script>
```

Comment: "the site sends my website a URL" - Can you elaborate on this, how is that other domain sending your website a URL?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unsure how that is happening. I wasn't given all the details. Is there a way for me to check? I do not have access to the other domain.

Comment: Would this be related to an iFrame Breaker?

Comment: Entirely unsure - you're saying that the other domain will send you a URL 'X' and you need to get your own page to go to that 'X'.  To go to that 'X', you need to find out how it's being sent.  You mention an iFrame breaker - that makes me think that you want to redirect your own page to wherever the iframe is about to go.  Does that sound closer to what you want?

Comment: @Shah yes, that is exactly what i want !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it appears that you are asking how you can detect the new `src` of the `iframe` after it has redirected.

Had your `iframe` page been in the same domain as your own, this would be no problem.  You would retrieve it like this:

```
document.getElementById("ID_OF_YOUR_IFRAME").contentWindow.location.href
```

But because it's an external domain, browsers will prevent you from do this as a security policy, you're [not allowed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815409/is-it-possible-to-find-a-cross-domain-iframes-new-url-after-a-redirect) access that information.