# Get redirected url from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an external url that redirect to another url. How can i get the redirected url using jquery ?

I was tryng with an iframe:

```
<iframe src="www.aurora.edu/~ddulany/" id="iframeid" ></iframe>
```

and

```
<script>
var frameLoadCount = 0;
var firstURL;

$('#iframeid').load(function() {
    if (frameLoadCount === 0) {
        firstURL = $(this).attr('src');
    } else {
        if (firstURL !== $(this).attr('src')) {
            alert($(this).attr('src'));
        }
    } 
});</script>
```

Comment: `$('iframeid')` is invalid selector  ... try `$('#iframeid')`. Provide more details if that isn't the issue

Comment: I was correcting the selector issue, however... nothing

Comment: need more details then...do some logging inside the callback. May need to add new load handler ... i forget if it persists or not

Comment: You can't access elements in an iframe from a different domain with JavaScript.  This is for security reasons, otherwise someone could load up an iframe off-screen , without you even knowing, and point it at any site of their choosing, such as your active cpanel session,and then with your session navigate to the file manager, create a new file, execute it, then compromise your entire server, etc.

Comment: I once had a client which wanted me to build them code which would allow a user to type personal info once and register on external sites in a bulk manner with an iframe. But I had to explain to him that this can't be done on the website I was building for him without having the user first download an `.HTA` file to get around the security restriction by running the code as an HTML Application which doesn't impose such security restrictions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815409/is-it-possible-to-find-a-cross-domain-iframes-new-url-after-a-redirect